# How to show a div after 5 right-clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make something that comes up after user right-clicked many times (5 clicks, for example). Then a div should be shown.

Right now I'm using this code:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() { 
    $("#red").fadeIn(500).show().delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
    return false;
};
```

This works fine, but it misess five attempts like I have said in my request.

UPDATE: Here the right code!

```
document.oncontextmenu = (function() {
var counter = 0;
return function() { 
    counter++;
    if (counter == 5) {
        $("#red").fadeIn(500).show().delay(3000).fadeOut(800, function() {
        counter = 0;
    });
    }
    return false;
};
```

})();

Thanks to @James Thorpe

Comment: What about using counter to check how many times user clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use what you have, but wrap it in a closure that has a variable to count how many times the inner function has been executed:

```
document.oncontextmenu = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function() { 
        counter++;
        if (counter == 5)
            $("#red").fadeIn(500).show().delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
        return false;
    };
})();
```

Note that the outer function is invoked immediately to create the variable, then returns the inner function as the event handler.  By using such a closure, we keep everything related to the event (including the counter variable) within the local scope without leaking anything to the global scope.

If you want to be able to invoke the div multiple times, you just need to reset the counter each time it's shown.  The best place to do that is in the [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#callback-function) supplied to the `fadeOut` function, so that the count only begins again once the div has been hidden.

```
if (counter == 5) {
    $("#red").fadeIn(500).show().delay(3000).fadeOut(800, function() {
        counter = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: @Redrif `if (counter == 5)`?

Comment: i mean where is the event that is catches whether the user right-clicked?

Comment: @Redrif That's the [`contextmenu` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu) that the OP is already binding to

Comment: @JamesThorpe, why do you self-execute the function you set to oncontextmenu?

Comment: oh, I see, for the counter. Nice!

Comment: @AmmarCSE I'm not, I'm self executing the outer function, which creates a local scope for the `counter` variable, and _returns the inner function_ to use as the event handler

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks, just tested your code... it works, but after the div go away, i will try to make other five clicks..but the div doesn't comes up no more... Its normal?

Comment: @Devilix You'd need to reset the counter if you want it able to show again.   I'll edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: @JamesThorpe i have add counter = 0; but now the div just not appear in any way... :(
Maybe there is something wrong
EDIT. My mistake... i was missing { }

Comment: Did you notice I changed the `if` to include braces (`{}`) since it now has a two statement body?  If the `counter = 0;` isn't included as part of the if statement, it will be resetting back to 0 every time you right click

Comment: There is a "memory effect" if i click repeatedly... Can we make something to stop this inconvenient?
I'm sorry, but i'm a beginner... :(

Comment: @JamesThorpe i'm talking about my comment of 30min ago...
There is a "memory effect" if i click repeatedly... and you have answered that "I think I know what you mean, I'll edit my answer again..."

Comment: @Devilix Yes - I edited again after that.  The counter is now being reset in the callback of `fadeout` - ie not until after the div has been hidden.  Any clicks that happen while it's open won't count

Comment: @JamesThorpe Hi, i need your help again... Did you can?

Comment: If you have a new question... Ask a new question :)  more people will see it and be able to help, this site is VERY active

Comment: But is related to this code! If is possible re-enable right-click on the <textarea>

Comment: You've not even mentioned a textarea until now - that very much sounds like a _different_ question - it may be related, but it's not the same issue!

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, i have a textarea where there is a html code for a banner... and I had not thought about this inconvenience :( sorry!
There is a simple solution? Or you suggest to open a new question?

Comment: @JamesThorpe if you can help me here... please! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822486/how-to-re-enable-rightclick-only-for-specific-tag-id